# How to achieve access and refresh token refreshing in next js server components?

Tags: express, next.js13

I have an express js backend. When a user signs in, an access and refresh token is sent to the user in an httpOnly cookie. The access token has an expiry time of 15 minutes and the refresh token has an expiry time of 7days. When an access token expires, the requests will start failing with 401 status code. After that, the client can make a request to refresh the tokens and if successfully refreshes, a new access and refresh token is sent back to the user. My question is this, how can i manage token refreshing in my server components in next js? how can i request for new tokens if the status code is 401 on the server and then retry the request.

I wanted to be able to refresh the tokens on the server components if the request to the backend failed with status code 401 and then retry the request after successfully refreshing the tokens